# How is it possible for float to hold a number as large as 3.4E38 when it's only 4 bytes?

Tags: c++, floating-point, size, byte, bit

Can anyone explain in **layman's term** how it's possible for a float to hold a number such large as 3.4E38 when its size is only 4 bytes?

Since this has 32 bits total, the largest number would be 2E31 + 2E30 + 2E29 + ... + 2E0, which is equivalent to 2147483647. So why can float hold such large number when int can hold only 2147483647 when both are practically the same size of 4 bytes?

I really appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: There are many questions which answer the issue raised here, directly or indirectly.  The one I chose is not necessarily the best, but it does seem apposite.  The answer is available from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), too — there are multiple relevant articles there.  There's also the classic [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf) paper too.

Answer (score 2):

Your question hints at the answer:

> How is it possible for float to hold a number as large as 3.4E38

How can "3.4E38" use so few numbers to refer to such a big value?  Well, it keeps a value in a set range (1 <= 3.4 < 10) on the left of `E` - with some smallish number of significant digits, and keeps an exponent `"38"` on the right - encoding a multiplication by 10^38 - that's also easy enough to store.

`float` values do the same thing, albeit in binary: 23 bits to store a mantissa (that's the "left" value) and 8 bits to store an exponent; the other bit is for positive/negative sign.

Fuller details at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

I also heartily recommend [this online "calculator"](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) which lets you type in a value like 3.4E38, see the binary representation (01111111011111111100100110011110), and a more accurate approximation of the value stored; you can even toggle the bits and see how they affect the value stored.

Comment: Thanks so much for helpful explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because float sacrifices precision to store large numbers. See [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/23850/67054) on Gamedev StackExchange site for a brief explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation Tony, I will check the link out.